# Exporting SQLite data to CSV

Tags: android, sql, excel, sqlite, android-sqlite

My task is to export data to CSV file. I am trying to generate a query before exporting data to a CSV File. Each student has a unique ID. As for now, I'm able to export the data in different tables separately and its working well.

Here is my current schema :

1) Student Table

```
 studID   | name | teacher | activity
 SQ202      Mich     Lisa    Hearing Test
 FG91A      Lim      Hanson  Behavioural Test
```

2) Session Table (Each student can have more than one session - not fixed)

```
 studID | startTime | endTime  | sessionNo | status
 SQ202      10:00      10:40        1        Completed
 SQ202      13:00      13:50        2        Completed
 FG91A      14:20      15:00        1        Completed
```

3) Interval Table (Each session can have more than four intervals - not fixed)

```
studID |sessionNum |intervalNo | score  
SQ202       1           1        10/10
SQ202       1           2        7/10
                 .
                 .
                 .
```

This is how I exported data from a specific table :

```
File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
if (!exportDir.exists()) {
  exportDir.mkdirs();
}

file = new File(exportDir, “ChildObservation" + " (D)" + date + " (T)" + time +".csv");
try {

  file.createNewFile();
  CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));


  // sqlite core query
  SQLiteDatabase db = myNewGradingDB.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor curChild = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Student ORDER BY name", null);
  csvWrite.writeNext(“Student ID”, “Name”, “Teacher”, “Activity");

  while (curChild.moveToNext()) {

  String arrStr[] = {
        curChild.getString(0), curChild.getString(1),
        curChild.getString(2), curChild.getString(3),
 };
 csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
 }

 csvWrite.writeNext();
 csvWrite.close();
 return true;
}

catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(“Child", e.getMessage(), e);
    return false;
}
```

However, my goal is to retrieve and display all the data tied to the student in a single row. Each row in the exported Excel sheet will contain all data from the Student table & Session table as well as from the respective interval number and scores from the Interval table. I have tried using inner joins and different kind of queries but there are still some duplicated values in those rows. Each cell must only contain one value, so in this case I won't be able to concatenate the columns in my query.

Here is what I want to achieve :

```
studID | name | teacher | activity        | startTime | endTime | sessionNo | status    | intervalNo | score | intervalNo | score ... (repeat intervalNo and score)
 SQ202   Mich    Lisa     Hearing Test       10:00      10:40       1         Completed      1         10/10       2        7/10  ...  
 FG91A   Lim     Hanson   Behavioural Test   12:30      1:40        2         Completed      1         8/10        2        6/10  ...
```

At this stage, its impossible for me to alter the database design. Perhaps there are other ways to resolve this, whether by SQL or another. Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So each dest row contains Student+session+Interval1+Interval2+Interval3+Interval4 data?

Comment: @k3b Yes thats right.

Comment: Looking at the requirement, I feel that it would be better (performance wise) to do the formatting at your program and not at the SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a sql only solution then
the trick to solve you problem is to join the interval table several times using an alias

```
select 
    st.studID, st.name,
    se.startTime, 
    i1.intervalNo as intervalNo1, i1.score as score1, 
    i2.intervalNo as intervalNo2, i2.score as score2, 
    i3.intervalNo as intervalNo3, i3.score as score3, 
    i4.intervalNo as intervalNo4, i4.score as score4

from Student as st 
    left join Session as se on st.studID = se.studID
    left join Interval as i1 on st.studID = i1.studID and i1.sessionNo=1
    left join Interval as i2 on st.studID = i2.studID and i2.sessionNo=2
    left join Interval as i3 on st.studID = i3.studID and i3.sessionNo=3
    left join Interval as i4 on st.studID = i4.studID and i4.sessionNo=4
```

but this only works if you know in advance how many interval-s there are